# If a 10 MB ﬁle is transferred over a 2 megabits per second connection, how many seconds it would take to transfer. using the nearest 0.1 second

Tags: connection, speed

Can someone please explain to me

If a 10 MB ﬁle is transferred over a 2 megabits per second connection, how many seconds it would take to transfer. using the nearest 0.1 second.
Thank you

Comment: hmm - phrased exactly like a homework question. hmmm.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you'll need to know is that 8 bit is one byte.

It's not common to calculate file sizes using bits, but it is possible: a 10MB file is 80megabits.

You could also calculate the connection in bytes: 2 megabit is 2/8 = 0.25 megabyte/s.

**Using bits**

80megabits at 2megabits/s

```
80/2 = 40s
```

**Using bytes**

10megabytes at 0.25megabytes/s

```
10/.25 = 40s
```

Comment: Of course this is only the theoretical speed, it will probably be slower due to the network conditions.

Comment: Unless you need to factor start and stop bits into the transmission.

Comment: True, but since the protocol isn't specified and the extra data negligible I left them out.